# A not so clear theorem about limits on the extrema of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition

In pag. 272 of *Analysis I* of Amann and Escher we can read

> Let $f:I\to\Bbb R$ monotone, $\alpha:=\inf I$ and $\beta :=\sup I$. Then
>
> $$\lim_{x\to\beta^-}f(x)=\begin{cases}\sup f(I),&\text{ if $f$ is increasing}\\\inf f(I),&\text{ if $f$ is decreasing}\end{cases}$$
>
> $$\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}f(x)=\begin{cases}\inf f(I),&\text{ if $f$ is increasing}\\\sup f(I),&\text{ if $f$ is decreasing}\end{cases}$$

where $I$ means here interval (it is not stated open, closed or anything, just any kind of interval). But this theorem is in clear conflict with one of the exercises of the chapter, that I tried to solve [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027306/prove-that-f-have-a-jump-discontinuity-at-any-rational-point).

A short definition of the function of the linked exercise:

> Let $\alpha:\Bbb N\to \Bbb Q$ a bijection, and a function
>
> $$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto \sum_{k\in N_x}y_k$$
>
> where $\sum_{k=0}^\infty y_k<\infty$ and $y_k>0$ for all $k$, and
>
> $$N_x:=\{k\in\Bbb N:\alpha(k)\le x\}$$

Then consider $r\in\Bbb Q$.

Following the linked exercise and using the above theorem we have that for a restriction on $f$ to some interval of the kind $(-\infty,r]$ have us

$$\lim_{x\to r^-}f(x)=\sup f((-\infty,r])=f(r)$$

because $f$ is strictly increasing. In the same way restricting $f$ to some set of the kind $[r,\infty)$ applying the cited theorem we have that

$$\lim_{x\to r^+}f(x)=\inf f([r,\infty))=f(r)$$

Then for $r\in\Bbb Q$ the function is continuous, following the above theorem. But the exercise ask to prove the discontinuity of $f$ at all rational points. So, where is the mistake? It is incorrect the theorem?

Comment: No, $\lim\limits_{x \to r^-} f(x) = \sup f((-\infty,r)) \neq \sup f((-\infty,r]) = f(r)$. For each of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you have to distinguish between the cases where the point belongs to the interval or not. If $f$ is increasing, then if $\beta\in I$, we have $\sup f(I) = f(\beta)$, but if $\beta\notin I$, then $\sup f(I) = \lim\limits_{x\to\beta^-} f(x)$ can be equal to $f(\beta)$ or strictly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you cite doesn't seem true. One should ask continuity for $f(x).$

However, as a counterexample, take

$$
f(x) = x + n \qquad  \text{for} \quad n - 1 < x \leq n.
$$

Of course in the interval $[1,2]$ you have

$$
\inf (f(x)) = f(1) = 2, \qquad \text{but} \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}f(x) = 3.
$$

So, you are right.