# Show that $f$ is everywhere discontinuous on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question from **R.L.Carothers-Real Analysis**;

> 13. Let ($r_ n$ ) be an enumeration of the rationals in $[ 0 , 1 ]$ and define $f$ on $[ 0, 1 ]$ by
>       $f(x) = \sum_{r_n<x} 2^{-n}$ . Show that $f $ is everywhere discontinuous on $[ 0, 1 ] $ but that $f$
>       is everywhere continuous when considered as a function on only $[ 0, 1 ] \setminus \Bbb Q$.

Let $a\in [0,1]$ .

To show that $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Now $f(a+h)=\sum _{r_n<a+h} 2^{-n}$ and $f(a)=\sum _{r_n<a} 2^{-n}$.

As $h\to 0\implies f(a+h)\to f(a)$

The problem is I am getting $f$ to be continuous.Where am I wrong ?

Comment: $f$ is continuous at all irrationals. It's discontinuous at the rationals.

Comment: Essentially [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027306/prove-that-f-have-a-jump-discontinuity-at-any-rational-point), only here the function is left-continuous and there it's right-continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer;Is the question in the book wrong then?

Comment: Yes, it is. $f$ is a monotonic function, and thus it can have at most countably many discontinuities. And all of its discontinuities are jump discontinuities.

Comment: I am afraid then ,if the problems are wrong in a book then is it safe to read it?@DanielFischer

Comment: I am just a beginner in analysis

Comment: Reading is never safe. It might lead to independent thought, and then insurgence. That aside, practically all books contain mistakes. Some mistakes are more serious than others, but a book having a mistake is no reason to discard it. If there are too many, or too egregious mistakes, that would be a reason. This one is a bit embarrassing for the author, but not damning.

Comment: Then should I continue with it?I am glad for your assurance

Comment: Just be aware of two things: a) Every book you read can have errors. b) If you and the book disagree, the first assumption should be that _you_ are the one mistaken. But one mustn't cling to that assumption for too long. If re-checking your argument carefully doesn't reveal an error, entertain the possibility that it's an error in the book, and ask somebody with more experience.

Comment: As long as you find the book explains things well, and gives proper proofs of the theorems, and you don't find too many errors (whether in the text or exercises), there's no real reason to drop it.

Comment: Gr8t to have a chat with you.As I am a beginner ,can you suggest me some books to grasp Real Analysis more efficiently

Comment: Take a look at Rudin's books (_Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ for the start, then _Real And Complex Analysis_). If you like Rudin's style, they are awesome. If you don't like the style, they are rather unpleasant I've been told. Royden's book and Folland's book on real analysis are also pretty good.